# How to merge both choose and Upload file in one button via AngularJS 1.x?

Tags: html, angularjs, css

instead of using two buttons separately to choose file and upload file, i want to do both operations in single button itself using custom directive and ng-change  in angulaJS, so how i can merge both type file and submit in a single button(choose and Upload file ) itself, please help me on this.
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Uber simple way:

```
<input ng-model="file" type="file"/>
```

Now just watch $scope.file and upload when it does in your controller.

Comment: I mean to say how I can achieve save image() and choose file in one button itself. I  am trying to use ng-change function.